# max() function in R gives wrong output

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R so I might be missing something obvious.
I've investigated some dataframes using R. I've also tried to provide some dummy data, but with the dummy data it suddenly works and the data that i am using are quite big. Maybe someone can help me anyway.

I've created a dataframe names haemasc with the columns "Wavelength" and "Absorbance" and wanted to know where my peak value for Absorbance was, so I wrote this:

```
haemasc[which(haem$Absorbance==max(haem$Absorbance)),]
```

which gives me the following output:

```
        Wavelength   Absorbance
109            408        1.647
```

which is just plain wrong, I've checked manually and the peak is in row 110 at Wavelength 409 with a value of 1.653 (see image attached) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i9x9.png)

curiously, it worked for the other dataframes i was investigating and also for my dummy data, so i really have no clue what went wrong.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? Preferably using `dput()`. Did you check your variables are numeric and not strings?

Comment: Why don't you also edit and add the code that you have used? That might help figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you check which row `max(haem$Absorbance)` itself returns? Could you try `sort(haem$Absorbance, decreasing=TRUE)` and see the ordering? For your problem, you can also use `which.max` to return the index of the maximum value.

Finally - while `which(haem$Absorbance==max(haem$Absorbance))` returns the index of the maximum value `haem$Absorbance`, you are looking up this index *in another data.frame*, `haemasc`.

Ah well, it's Monday and we've all been there. :)

Comment: oh wow - i completely missed that, haha. thanks for pointing that out! :D